# Prove that the board contains a nontrivial rectangle.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

A 3 × 7 rectangle is divided into 21 squares each of which is colored
red or black. Prove that the board contains a nontrivial rectangle (not
`1 × k` or `k`) whose four corner squares are all black or all red.

I have drawn the board but I do not know what the question is asking. What does it mean by nontrivial rectangle (not `1 × k` or `k`)? Really stuck with this.

Comment: Presumably they meant "not $1 \times k$ or $k \times 1$." that is, we don't want to count a single square as a "rectangle", nor a line that's only 1 square wide.

Comment: It seems that a nontrivial rectangle is one whose sides are all greater than 1 unit.

Comment: Also by corners does it mean the inside squares or the outside single squares from the big one?

Answer (score 1):

The board has $7$ columns of three squares each, call a column red if it has more red squares and black if it has more black squares. There must be at least $4$ columns of a given color. Without loss of generality assume that color is red.

Thus there are at least $4$ red columns. For each red column select two red squares of that column. Notice there are in general three ways to do this (the top squares, bottom squares or outer squares).

Since there are more than three red columns there must be two which have the same selected squares in their respective columns. These four selected squares form the desired rectangle.

Comment: http://imgur.com/LJDlHQk
So we have 4 red squares as columns. Then the two squares for each column part I am confused about.

Comment: Yeah, for each red column select two red squares.

Comment: do that in your drawing and show it to me

Comment: http://imgur.com/qRUj8Xy green is the selected squares for each column

Comment: Ok, in this case tyou selected the same squares for all columns. However it doesn't necessarily have to be like that. The point is that there are only three possible positions in which they can be chosen. And there are four columns, so there must be two columns for which you selected the same squares and those four squares will form the desired rectangle. In your case you can select any of the red columns and the four selected squares will form a rectangle